# Javascript function works on postback but not page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm using a Google Maps plugin, and I want it to show up on the page load as well as all postbacks. It seems to only work on postbacks though. Any ideas? I have the body onload tag as "body background="#ccccff" onload="initialize()"", but the function is not defined the first time. Why? Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mostRecentInfo;
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: center,
        zoom:1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var posStr = <%=JSON%>;
    if (posStr.toString() != "0") {
        var test = posStr.toString().split(',');            
        var groundstation = <%=groundStation%>;
        var dateTimeStr = <%=datetimesStr%>;
        var AUStr = <%=auStr%>;
        var spaceCraft = <%=spacecraft%>;
        var dateTimes = dateTimeStr.toString().split(',');
        var auIDs = AUStr.toString().split(',');
        var latitude = new Array((test.length / 2));
        var longitude = new Array(latitude.length);
        var i = 0;
        var markerArray = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < (test.length - 1); j = j + 2) {
            latitude[i] = eval(test[j+1]);
            longitude[i] = eval(test[j]);
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i], longitude[i]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position:position
            });
            markerArray.push(marker);
            i++;
        }
        var sumLat = 0;
        var sumLong = 0;            
        for (i = 0; i < latitude.length; i++) {
            sumLat += latitude[i];
            sumLong += longitude[i];
        }
        var avgLat = sumLat / latitude.length;
        var avgLong = sumLong / longitude.length;
        center = new google.maps.LatLng(avgLat, avgLong);
        map.panTo(center); 
        var circle; 
        var contentStr = new Array();                       
        for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
            position = markerArray[i].getPosition();
            var circOptions = {
                strokeColor:"#770000",
                strokeOpacity:0.1,
                fillColor:"#881111",
                fillOpacity:0.4,
                map:map,
                center:position,
                radius:2500000
            };
            circle = new google.maps.Circle(circOptions);
            marker = markerArray[i];
            contentStr[i] = '<div id="content">' +
                '<b>Spacecraft: </b>' + spaceCraft.toString() + '<br />' +
                '<b>Start Time (UTC): </b>' + dateTimes[i].toString() + '<br />' +                  
                '<b>Position: </b>(' + latitude[i].toString() + ', ' + longitude[i].toString() + ')<br />' +
                '<b>AU ID: </b>' + auIDs[i] + '<br />' +
                '<b>Downlink Station: </b>' + groundstation.toString() + '<br />' +
                '</div>';
            addListener(map, marker, contentStr[i]);
        }
    }         
}

function addListener(map, marker, content) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:content
        });               
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        if (mostRecentInfo) 
            mostRecentInfo.close();
        mostRecentInfo = infowindow;
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

etc.

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger. Go to youtube.com and search for 'using chrome to debug javascript.' Now you can step through your code line by line and see where it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely a timing issue with the `onload` function being called before the initialize function is ready. This is the reason libraries like jQuery have a document.ready function. You can try removing the `onload` and place a call to `initialize()` at the bottom of your HTML, just prior to the closing `body` tag. This will probably work for you.

If you have the option, I'd use a library so you can assure that the function is there and your page is ready. If you haven't tried it, give [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) a shot.